# Overlapping TextView

Tags: android, textview

I have a problem with first TextView. When text is too long it overlaps the second one and it looks like one text over antoher. How can I make first (@+id/nazwa) to go to the second line when encountering the latter?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/nazwa" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/odleglosc"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to just add two line in first textView

```
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/odleglosc"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

Like below

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nazwa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/odleglosc"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Put them in a `LinearLayout` (`horizontal`), give them both a `width` of `0dp` and a `weight` of `1` and they will share the horizontal space and not overlap.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want them to be below when it's to large, you can take a look at the width of the text

```
Rect bounds = new Rect();
Paint textPaint = textView.getPaint();
textPaint.getTextBounds(text,0,text.length(),bounds);
int height = bounds.height();
int width = bounds.width();
```

If this width is larger than you want, you can rearrange the view trough code.

If you want to have the two side by side an want them to add a line if they are to large try something like this

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/nazwa" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/odleglosc"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: but I need it to be `RelativeLayout` - one TextView must be to the left and the other to the right.

Comment: Can you show a quick sketch or design? (Problem and goal)

Comment: what do you need the RelativeLayout for?

Comment: I want to have one text to the left and the second one to the right. I couldn't obtain that with LinearLayout. It's a design for list row - product and price.